# What's the deal with the banner command?

Tags: unix, standards

In some versions of UNIX and Linux there's a banner command (usually /usr/bin/banner) that prints great output like this:

```
 #####  #######    #     #####  #    #
#     #    #      # #   #     # #   #
#          #     #   #  #       #  #
 #####     #    #     # #       ###
      #    #    ####### #       #  #
#     #    #    #     # #     # #   #
 #####     #    #     #  #####  #    #
```

In other versions, the banner command (frequently /usr/games/banner) prints an ENORMOUS banner like you'd make in 1980 with Printshop that are suited for use at birthday parties and stuff.

I tend to love using banner for my scripts but it inherently non-portable because of this issue. Is "banner" part of UNIX and why isn't part of the POSIX standards? This is some BSD vs SysV difference but why hasn't it been resolved?

I know there's figlet which reproduces the banner that I like. But my issue with this command is portability. Banner *should* be part of UNIX, IMHO, even if they need to include both versions under *different* names (although ideally the behavior should be merged into one command with an option for the desired output).

Am I just crap out of luck when it comes to portability in scripts if I use banner?

Comment: A pure Perl version is https://metacpan.org/release/Text-Banner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there were the two divergent behaviours when POSIX was standardized, back in the late 80s, `banner` was omitted from the standard.  It was not essential and there wasn't a prevailing standard to select as 'the standard'.

And yes, you are out of luck if you use `banner` in your script; the behaviour is not reliable across platforms.

Answer (score 17):

Nothing is more portable across Unices as straight C.

You might find my rough draft here easier to modify and extend than one from a distribution (due to the implicit copyright if nothing else). This code was designed to be easy to read and understand without any comments.

[*Don't be afraid of that big array, the actual code is very short. And at the very bottom there are "comments" which were used to visualize and construct the bitmaps. If you can understand why the space character works despite being coded as a backslash, then you understand the whole thing. The rest is just filling out the alphabet.*]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    A = 1<<0,
    B = 1<<1,
    C = 1<<2,
    D = 1<<3,
    E = 1<<4,
    F = 1<<5,
    G = 1<<6,
    H = 1<<7,
};

char vec[] = " 0123456789"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    ".,:!/\\|+-*=";

unsigned char map[sizeof(vec)][8] = {
    /* */ {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H}, /* :) */
    /*0*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|F|G, A|E|G, A|D|G, A|C|G, A|B|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*1*/ {G, F|G, G, G, G, G, G, 0},
    /*2*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, G, C|D|E|F, B, A, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, 0},
    /*3*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, G, C|D|E|F, G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*4*/ {A|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|F|G, F, F, F, 0},
    /*5*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F|G, A, A, B|C|D|E|F, G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*6*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A, A, A|B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*7*/ {B|C|D|E|F|G, G, F, E, D, C, B, 0},
    /*8*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*9*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F|G, G, G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*a*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, F, B|C|D|E|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|G, 0},
    /*b*/ {B, B, B, B|C|D|E|F, B|G, B|G, A|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*c*/ {0, 0, C|D|E, B|F, A, A, B|F, C|D|E},
    /*d*/ {F, F, F, B|C|D|E|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|G, 0},
    /*e*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, A|F, A|B|C|D|E|F, A, B|C|D|E, 0},
    /*f*/ {C|D|E, B, B, A|B|C|D, B, B, B, 0},
    /*g*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E|G, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E, F, B|C|D|E},
    /*h*/ {B, B, B, B|C|D|E, B|F, B|F, A|B|F, 0},
    /*i*/ {0, C, 0, B|C, C, C, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
    /*j*/ {0, D, 0, D, D, D, A|D, B|C},
    /*k*/ {B, B|E, B|D, B|C, B|D, B|E, A|B|E|F, 0},
    /*l*/ {A|B, B, B, B, B, B, A|B|C, 0},
    /*m*/ {0, 0, 0, A|C|E|F, A|B|D|G, A|D|G, A|D|G, 0},
    /*n*/ {0, 0, 0, B|D|E, B|C|F, B|F, B|F, 0},
    /*o*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, A|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E, 0},
    /*p*/ {0, 0, A|B|C|D|E, B|F, B|F, B|C|D|E, B, A|B},
    /*q*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E|G, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E, F, F|G},
    /*r*/ {0, 0, A|B|D|E, B|C|F, B, B, A|B, 0},
    /*s*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, A, B|C|D|E, F, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
    /*t*/ {0, C, C, A|B|C|D|E, C, C, D|E, 0},
    /*u*/ {0, 0, A|F, A|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|G, 0},
    /*v*/ {0, 0, A|G, B|F, B|F, C|E, D, 0},
    /*w*/ {0, 0, A|G, A|G, A|D|G, A|D|G, B|C|E|F, 0},
    /*x*/ {0, 0, A|F, B|E, C|D, B|E, A|F, 0},
    /*y*/ {0, 0, B|F, B|F, B|F, C|F, A|D|E, B|C|D},
    /*z*/ {0, 0, A|B|C|D|E|F, E, D, C, B|C|D|E|F|G, 0},
    /*A*/ {D, C|E, B|F, A|G, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, A|G, A|G, 0},
    /*B*/ {A|B|C|D|E, A|F, A|F, A|B|C|D|E, A|F, A|F, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
    /*C*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A, A, A, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
    /*D*/ {A|B|C|D, A|E, A|F, A|F, A|F, A|E, A|B|C|D, 0},
    /*E*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F, A, A, A|B|C|D|E, A, A, A|B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*F*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F, A, A, A|B|C|D|E, A, A, A, 0},
    /*G*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A, A, A|E|F|G, B|F|G, C|D|E|G, 0},
    /*H*/ {A|G, A|G, A|G, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, 0},
    /*I*/ {A|B|C|D|E, C, C, C, C, C, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
    /*J*/ {A|B|C|D|E, C, C, C, C, C, A|C, B},
    /*K*/ {A|F, A|E, A|D, A|B|C, A|D, A|E, A|F, 0},
    /*L*/ {A, A, A, A, A, A, A|B|C|D|E|F, 0},
    /*M*/ {A|B|F|G, A|C|E|G, A|D|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, 0},
    /*N*/ {A|G, A|B|G, A|C|G, A|D|G, A|E|G, A|F|G, A|G, 0},
    /*O*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A|G, A|G, A|G, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
    /*P*/ {A|B|C|D, A|E, A|E, A|B|C|D, A, A, A, 0},
    /*Q*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A|G, A|G, A|C|G, B|D|F, C|D|E, F|G},
    /*R*/ {A|B|C|D, A|E, A|E, A|B|C|D, A|E, A|F, A|F, 0},
    /*S*/ {C|D|E, B|F, C, D, E, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
    /*T*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F|G, D, D, D, D, D, D, 0},
    /*U*/ {A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
    /*V*/ {A|G, A|G, B|F, B|F, C|E, C|E, D, 0},
    /*W*/ {A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, A|D|G, A|C|E|G, B|F, 0},
    /*X*/ {A|G, A|G, B|F, C|D|E, B|F, A|G, A|G, 0},
    /*Y*/ {A|G, A|G, B|F, C|E, D, D, D, 0},
    /*Z*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F|G, F, E, D, C, B, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, 0},
    /*.*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, D, 0},
    /*,*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E, E, D},
    /*:*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, D, 0, D, 0},
    /*!*/ {D, D, D, D, D, 0, D, 0},
    /*/ */ {G, F, E, D, C, B, A, 0},
    /*\\*/ {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0},
    /*|*/ {D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D},
    /*+*/ {0, D, D, B|C|D|E|F, D, D, 0, 0},
    /*-*/ {0, 0, 0, B|C|D|E|F, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    /***/ {0, B|D|F, C|D|E, D, C|D|E, B|D|F, 0, 0},
    /*=*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E|F, 0, B|C|D|E|F, 0, 0, 0}
};

int enc(int c) { return strchr(vec,c)-vec; }

void show(char *s) {
    int row,col;
    char *sp;
    for (row=0; row<8; row++, putchar('\n'))
        for (sp = s; *sp; sp++)
            if (strchr(vec,*sp)!=NULL)
                for (col=0; col<8; col++)
                    putchar(map[enc(*sp)][row] & 1<<col ? *sp:' ');
}

int main(int c,char **v) {
    for (--c,++v;*v;v++,c--) show(*v);
    return 0;
}


/*
   01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
0   #####               #           ###               #
1  #     #              #          #                  #
2  #     #    ####      #          #        #### #    #
3   #####         #     #####    #####     #    #     ####
4  #     #    #####     #    #     #       #    #     #   #
5  #     #   #    #     #    #     #        ####      #   #
6   #####     #### #   # ####      #            #    ##   #
7                                           ####
*/

/*
   01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
0                       #
1    #          #       #  #
2                       # #      #         #####      #### #
3   ##          #       ##       ### ##     #   #    #    #
4    #          #       # #      #  #  #    #   #    #    #
5    #          #       #  #     #  #  #    ####      ####
6  #####     #  #      ##  ##    ## #  #    #             #
7             ##                           ##             ##
*/

/*
   01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
0
1
2  ## ##      ####     #    #     #   #    ######    #     #
3   ##  #    #          #  #      #   #        #     #     #
4   #         ####       ##       #   #       #      #  #  #
5   #             #     #  #       #  #      #       #  #  #
6  ##        #####     #    #    #  ##      ######    ## ##
7                                 ###
*/

/*
   01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
0     #      #####       ###     ####      #####     #     #
1    # #     #    #     #   #    #   #       #       #     #
2   #   #    #    #    #         #    #      #       #     #
3   #   #    #####     #         #    #      #       #     #
4   #####    #    #    #         #    #      #       #  #  #
5  #     #   #    #     #   #    #   #       #       # # # #
6  #     #   #####       ###     ####      # #        #   #
7                                           #
*/
```

Comment: That is really cool! I'll have to pick apart the source someday as a fun project. There actually is a portable way... I wrote a banner command using awk script since I last thought about this topic. ;-) I'll post it someday when I'm on that computer.

Comment: I considered adding an option to set the display character to something other than the source char (like # or *) but then I'd have to change the glyph for space!

Comment: I only upvoted you because I never knew what the plural of 'unix' was before :-)

Comment: Awesome code! Tnx!

Answer (score 11):

The desired banner is the System V banner,
install the sysvbanner package to get it,
at least on Ubuntu 11

Comment: FYI on ubuntu 12.04: `apt-get install sysvbanner` worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Here is a shell implementation inspired from @luser droog's code. It is not POSIX compliant but works with both ksh93 and bash, which make it portable enough for most current Unix implementations.

```
#!/bin/ksh93
# or #!/bin/bash

A=$((1<<0))
B=$((1<<1))
C=$((1<<2))
D=$((1<<3))
E=$((1<<4))
F=$((1<<5))
G=$((1<<6))
H=$((1<<7))

function outLine
{
  typeset r=0 scan
  for scan
  do
    typeset l=${#scan}
    typeset line=0
    for ((p=0; p<l; p++))
    do
      line="$((line+${scan:$p:1}))"
    done
    for ((column=0; column<8; column++))
      do
        [[ $((line & (1<<column))) == 0 ]] && n=" " || n="#"
        raw[r]="${raw[r]}$n"
      done
      r=$((r+1))
    done
}

function outChar
{
    case "$1" in
    (" ") outLine "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ;;
    ("0") outLine "BCDEF" "AFG" "AEG" "ADG" "ACG" "ABG" "BCDEF" "" ;;
    ("1") outLine "F" "EF" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "" ;;
    ("2") outLine "BCDEF" "AG" "G" "CDEF" "B" "A" "ABCDEFG" "" ;;
    ("3") outLine "BCDEF" "AG" "G" "CDEF" "G" "AG" "BCDEF" "" ;;
    ("4") outLine "AF" "AF" "AF" "BCDEFG" "F" "F" "F" "" ;;
    ("5") outLine "ABCDEFG" "A" "A" "ABCDEF" "G" "AG" "BCDEF" "" ;;
    ("6") outLine "BCDEF" "A" "A" "BCDEF" "AG" "AG" "BCDEF" "" ;;
    ("7") outLine "BCDEFG" "G" "F" "E" "D" "C" "B" "" ;;
    ("8") outLine "BCDEF" "AG" "AG" "BCDEF" "AG" "AG" "BCDEF" "" ;;
    ("9") outLine "BCDEF" "AG" "AG" "BCDEF" "G" "G" "BCDEF" "" ;;
    ("a") outLine "" "" "BCDE" "F" "BCDEF" "AF" "BCDEG" "" ;;
    ("b") outLine "B" "B" "BCDEF" "BG" "BG" "BG" "ACDEF" "" ;;
    ("c") outLine "" "" "CDE" "BF" "A" "BF" "CDE" "" ;;
    ("d") outLine "F" "F" "BCDEF" "AF" "AF" "AF" "BCDEG" "" ;;
    ("e") outLine "" "" "BCDE" "AF" "ABCDEF" "A" "BCDE" "" ;;
    ("f") outLine "CDE" "B" "B" "ABCD" "B" "B" "B" "" ;;
    ("g") outLine "" "" "BCDEG" "AF" "AF" "BCDE" "F" "BCDE" ;;
    ("h") outLine "B" "B" "BCDE" "BF" "BF" "BF" "ABF" "" ;;
    ("i") outLine "C" "" "BC" "C" "C" "C" "ABCDE" "" ;;
    ("j") outLine "D" "" "CD" "D" "D" "D" "AD" "BC" ;;
    ("k") outLine "B" "BE" "BD" "BC" "BD" "BE" "ABEF" "" ;;
    ("l") outLine "AB" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "ABC" "" ;;
    ("m") outLine "" "" "ACEF" "ABDG" "ADG" "ADG" "ADG" "" ;;
    ("n") outLine "" "" "BDE" "BCF" "BF" "BF" "BF" "" ;;
    ("o") outLine "" "" "BCDE" "AF" "AF" "AF" "BCDE" "" ;;
    ("p") outLine "" "" "ABCDE" "BF" "BF" "BCDE" "B" "AB" ;;
    ("q") outLine "" "" "BCDEG" "AF" "AF" "BCDE" "F" "FG" ;;
    ("r") outLine "" "" "ABDE" "BCF" "B" "B" "AB" "" ;;
    ("s") outLine "" "" "BCDE" "A" "BCDE" "F" "ABCDE" "" ;;
    ("t") outLine "C" "C" "ABCDE" "C" "C" "C" "DE" "" ;;
    ("u") outLine "" "" "AF" "AF" "AF" "AF" "BCDEG" "" ;;
    ("v") outLine "" "" "AG" "BF" "BF" "CE" "D" "" ;;
    ("w") outLine "" "" "AG" "AG" "ADG" "ADG" "BCEF" "" ;;
    ("x") outLine "" "" "AF" "BE" "CD" "BE" "AF" "" ;;
    ("y") outLine "" "" "BF" "BF" "BF" "CDE" "E" "BCD" ;;
    ("z") outLine "" "" "ABCDEF" "E" "D" "C" "BCDEFG" "" ;;
    ("A") outLine "D" "CE" "BF" "AG" "ABCDEFG" "AG" "AG" "" ;;
    ("B") outLine "ABCDE" "AF" "AF" "ABCDE" "AF" "AF" "ABCDE" "" ;;
    ("C") outLine "CDE" "BF" "A" "A" "A" "BF" "CDE" "" ;;
    ("D") outLine "ABCD" "AE" "AF" "AF" "AF" "AE" "ABCD" "" ;;
    ("E") outLine "ABCDEF" "A" "A" "ABCDE" "A" "A" "ABCDEF" "" ;;
    ("F") outLine "ABCDEF" "A" "A" "ABCDE" "A" "A" "A" "" ;;
    ("G") outLine "CDE" "BF" "A" "A" "AEFG" "BFG" "CDEG" "" ;;
    ("H") outLine "AG" "AG" "AG" "ABCDEFG" "AG" "AG" "AG" "" ;;
    ("I") outLine "ABCDE" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "ABCDE" "" ;;
    ("J") outLine "BCDEF" "D" "D" "D" "D" "BD" "C" "" ;;
    ("K") outLine "AF" "AE" "AD" "ABC" "AD" "AE" "AF" "" ;;
    ("L") outLine "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "ABCDEF" "" ;;
    ("M") outLine "ABFG" "ACEG" "ADG" "AG" "AG" "AG" "AG" "" ;;
    ("N") outLine "AG" "ABG" "ACG" "ADG" "AEG" "AFG" "AG" "" ;;
    ("O") outLine "CDE" "BF" "AG" "AG" "AG" "BF" "CDE" "" ;;
    ("P") outLine "ABCDE" "AF" "AF" "ABCDE" "A" "A" "A" "" ;;
    ("Q") outLine "CDE" "BF" "AG" "AG" "ACG" "BDF" "CDE" "FG" ;;
    ("R") outLine "ABCD" "AE" "AE" "ABCD" "AE" "AF" "AF" "" ;;
    ("S") outLine "CDE" "BF" "C" "D" "E" "BF" "CDE" "" ;;
    ("T") outLine "ABCDEFG" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "" ;;
    ("U") outLine "AG" "AG" "AG" "AG" "AG" "BF" "CDE" "" ;;
    ("V") outLine "AG" "AG" "BF" "BF" "CE" "CE" "D" "" ;;
    ("W") outLine "AG" "AG" "AG" "AG" "ADG" "ACEG" "BF" "" ;;
    ("X") outLine "AG" "AG" "BF" "CDE" "BF" "AG" "AG" "" ;;
    ("Y") outLine "AG" "AG" "BF" "CE" "D" "D" "D" "" ;;
    ("Z") outLine "ABCDEFG" "F" "E" "D" "C" "B" "ABCDEFG" "" ;;
    (".") outLine "" "" "" "" "" "" "D" "" ;;
    (",") outLine "" "" "" "" "" "E" "E" "D" ;;
    (":") outLine "" "" "" "" "D" "" "D" "" ;;
    ("!") outLine "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "" "D" "" ;;
    ("/") outLine "G" "F" "E" "D" "C" "B" "A" "" ;;
    ("\\") outLine "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "" ;;
    ("|") outLine "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" ;;
    ("+") outLine "" "D" "D" "BCDEF" "D" "D" "" "" ;;
    ("-") outLine "" "" "" "BCDEF" "" "" "" "" ;;
    ("*") outLine "" "BDF" "CDE" "D" "CDE" "BDF" "" "" ;;
    ("=") outLine "" "" "BCDEF" "" "BCDEF" "" "" "" ;;
    (*) outLine "ABCDEFGH" "AH" "AH" "AH" "AH" "AH" "AH" "ABCDEFGH" ;;
    esac
}

function outArg
{
  typeset l=${#1} c r
  for ((c=0; c<l; c++))
  do
    outChar "${1:$c:1}"
  done
  echo
  [ -z "$COLUMNS" ] && COLUMNS=$(tput cols 2>/dev/null)
  for ((r=0; r<8; r++))
  do
    printf "%-*.*s\n" "${COLUMNS:-80}" "${COLUMNS:-80}" "${raw[r]}"
    raw[r]=""
  done
}

for i
do
  outArg "$i"
  echo
done
```

Comment: I added this line to the script (just before the final `for` loop): `COLUMNS=$(/usr/bin/tput cols)` to have it automatically fit my xterm size (which is much bigger than 80 cols).

Comment: @MarkLakata Thanks, answer updated to handle the case COLUMNS is not set but settable.

Comment: Even more awesome shell code!!! Tnx!!!

Comment: @shellter Thanks. When I saw luser_droog's code, I thought it would be fun to port it to shell. That was 11 years ago but I still remember it :-)

Comment: I did a similar conversion for a  shell script using `var=$(grep trgt file) | cut -f3)` sort of processing for each line into one `awk` script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651542/bash-dihedral-angle-with-four-points/46652971 . Cheers! (I didn't/don't understand the math, but it worked for O.P. (6+years aga) (-;! )

Answer (score 8):

There's always [FIGLet](http://www.figlet.org/). Gives source for unix, windows, dos, mac etc. hope this points you in the right direction.

Also, there's [TOIlet](http://caca.zoy.org/toilet.html), which could be considered figlet++.

Comment: thats pretty cool, but I thing the propoent is looking for something they can put into makefiles during builds for use as a header on a build report etc.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't really essential to a unix system, I am not sure why it would be part of the standard.  There are a many other things that are arguably more important that the standard setting bodies should be focused on.

If it isn't available on the system you could simply install it or build a equivalent.

There is a banner clone on debian it has a single c file with 155 lines of code, and most of that is just the glyphs.  The source can be found on the package page.
http://packages.debian.org/testing/misc/sysvbanner

It shouldn't be too difficult to even build another clone in the scripting language of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

The banner command from bsdmainutils package version 8.0.13 is now called printerbanner and is located here /usr/bin/printerbanner.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested, here's a Java version. It generates a String, and it's up to you whether you use System.out.println() or your Logging framework of choice.

```
public class Banner {
    public static String print(String s, char stdCh) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            sb.append('\n');
            for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
                int enc = CHAR_LIST.indexOf(ch);
                if (enc < 0) continue;
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    sb.append(isPresent(row, enc, col) ? charToPrint(ch, stdCh) : ' ');
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.append('\n').toString();
    }

    private static char charToPrint(char ch, char stdCh) {
        return ch != ' ' && stdCh != 0 ? stdCh : ch;
    }

    private static boolean isPresent(int row, int enc, int col) {
        return (map[enc][row] & 1 << col) != 0;
    }

    // @formatter:off
    private static final String CHAR_LIST = " 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,:!/\\|+-*=";

    private static int        A = 1<<0;
    private static int        B = 1<<1;
    private static int        C = 1<<2;
    private static int        D = 1<<3;
    private static int        E = 1<<4;
    private static int        F = 1<<5;
    private static int        G = 1<<6;
    private static int        H = 1<<7;

    // define the 'font'
    private static int[][] map = new int[][] {
        /* */ {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H},
        /*0*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|F|G, A|E|G, A|D|G, A|C|G, A|B|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*1*/ {G, F|G, G, G, G, G, G, 0},
        /*2*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, G, C|D|E|F, B, A, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, 0},
        /*3*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, G, C|D|E|F, G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*4*/ {A|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|F|G, F, F, F, 0},
        /*5*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F|G, A, A, B|C|D|E|F, G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*6*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A, A, A|B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*7*/ {B|C|D|E|F|G, G, F, E, D, C, B, 0},
        /*8*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*9*/ {B|C|D|E|F, A|G, A|G, B|C|D|E|F|G, G, G, B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*a*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, F, B|C|D|E|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|G, 0},
        /*b*/ {B, B, B, B|C|D|E|F, B|G, B|G, A|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*c*/ {0, 0, C|D|E, B|F, A, A, B|F, C|D|E},
        /*d*/ {F, F, F, B|C|D|E|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|G, 0},
        /*e*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, A|F, A|B|C|D|E|F, A, B|C|D|E, 0},
        /*f*/ {C|D|E, B, B, A|B|C|D, B, B, B, 0},
        /*g*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E|G, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E, F, B|C|D|E},
        /*h*/ {B, B, B, B|C|D|E, B|F, B|F, A|B|F, 0},
        /*i*/ {0, C, 0, B|C, C, C, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
        /*j*/ {0, D, 0, D, D, D, A|D, B|C},
        /*k*/ {B, B|E, B|D, B|C, B|D, B|E, A|B|E|F, 0},
        /*l*/ {A|B, B, B, B, B, B, A|B|C, 0},
        /*m*/ {0, 0, 0, A|C|E|F, A|B|D|G, A|D|G, A|D|G, 0},
        /*n*/ {0, 0, 0, B|D|E, B|C|F, B|F, B|F, 0},
        /*o*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, A|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E, 0},
        /*p*/ {0, 0, A|B|C|D|E, B|F, B|F, B|C|D|E, B, A|B},
        /*q*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E|G, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E, F, F|G},
        /*r*/ {0, 0, A|B|D|E, B|C|F, B, B, A|B, 0},
        /*s*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E, A, B|C|D|E, F, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
        /*t*/ {0, C, C, A|B|C|D|E, C, C, D|E, 0},
        /*u*/ {0, 0, A|F, A|F, A|F, A|F, B|C|D|E|G, 0},
        /*v*/ {0, 0, A|G, B|F, B|F, C|E, D, 0},
        /*w*/ {0, 0, A|G, A|G, A|D|G, A|D|G, B|C|E|F, 0},
        /*x*/ {0, 0, A|F, B|E, C|D, B|E, A|F, 0},
        /*y*/ {0, 0, B|F, B|F, B|F, C|F, A|D|E, B|C|D},
        /*z*/ {0, 0, A|B|C|D|E|F, E, D, C, B|C|D|E|F|G, 0},
        /*A*/ {D, C|E, B|F, A|G, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, A|G, A|G, 0},
        /*B*/ {A|B|C|D|E, A|F, A|F, A|B|C|D|E, A|F, A|F, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
        /*C*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A, A, A, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
        /*D*/ {A|B|C|D, A|E, A|F, A|F, A|F, A|E, A|B|C|D, 0},
        /*E*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F, A, A, A|B|C|D|E, A, A, A|B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*F*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F, A, A, A|B|C|D|E, A, A, A, 0},
        /*G*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A, A, A|E|F|G, B|F|G, C|D|E|G, 0},
        /*H*/ {A|G, A|G, A|G, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, 0},
        /*I*/ {A|B|C|D|E, C, C, C, C, C, A|B|C|D|E, 0},
        /*J*/ {A|B|C|D|E, C, C, C, C, C, A|C, B},
        /*K*/ {A|F, A|E, A|D, A|B|C, A|D, A|E, A|F, 0},
        /*L*/ {A, A, A, A, A, A, A|B|C|D|E|F, 0},
        /*M*/ {A|B|F|G, A|C|E|G, A|D|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, 0},
        /*N*/ {A|G, A|B|G, A|C|G, A|D|G, A|E|G, A|F|G, A|G, 0},
        /*O*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A|G, A|G, A|G, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
        /*P*/ {A|B|C|D, A|E, A|E, A|B|C|D, A, A, A, 0},
        /*Q*/ {C|D|E, B|F, A|G, A|G, A|C|G, B|D|F, C|D|E, F|G},
        /*R*/ {A|B|C|D, A|E, A|E, A|B|C|D, A|E, A|F, A|F, 0},
        /*S*/ {C|D|E, B|F, C, D, E, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
        /*T*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F|G, D, D, D, D, D, D, 0},
        /*U*/ {A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, B|F, C|D|E, 0},
        /*V*/ {A|G, A|G, B|F, B|F, C|E, C|E, D, 0},
        /*W*/ {A|G, A|G, A|G, A|G, A|D|G, A|C|E|G, B|F, 0},
        /*X*/ {A|G, A|G, B|F, C|D|E, B|F, A|G, A|G, 0},
        /*Y*/ {A|G, A|G, B|F, C|E, D, D, D, 0},
        /*Z*/ {A|B|C|D|E|F|G, F, E, D, C, B, A|B|C|D|E|F|G, 0},
        /*.*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, D, 0},
        /*,*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E, E, D},
        /*:*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, D, 0, D, 0},
        /*!*/ {D, D, D, D, D, 0, D, 0},
        /*/ */ {G, F, E, D, C, B, A, 0},
        /*\\*/ {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0},
        /*|*/ {D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D},
        /*+*/ {0, D, D, B|C|D|E|F, D, D, 0, 0},
        /*-*/ {0, 0, 0, B|C|D|E|F, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        /***/ {0, B|D|F, C|D|E, D, C|D|E, B|D|F, 0, 0},
        /*=*/ {0, 0, B|C|D|E|F, 0, B|C|D|E|F, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    /*
       01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
    0   #####               #           ###               #
    1  #     #              #          #                  #
    2  #     #    ####      #          #        #### #    #
    3   #####         #     #####    #####     #    #     ####
    4  #     #    #####     #    #     #       #    #     #   #
    5  #     #   #    #     #    #     #        ####      #   #
    6   #####     #### #   # ####      #            #    ##   #
    7                                           ####
    */

    /*
       01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
    0                       #
    1    #          #       #  #
    2                       # #      #         #####      #### #
    3   ##          #       ##       ### ##     #   #    #    #
    4    #          #       # #      #  #  #    #   #    #    #
    5    #          #       #  #     #  #  #    ####      ####
    6  #####     #  #      ##  ##    ## #  #    #             #
    7             ##                           ##             ##
    */

    /*
       01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
    0
    1
    2  ## ##      ####     #    #     #   #    ######    #     #
    3   ##  #    #          #  #      #   #        #     #     #
    4   #         ####       ##       #   #       #      #  #  #
    5   #             #     #  #       #  #      #       #  #  #
    6  ##        #####     #    #    #  ##      ######    ## ##
    7                                 ###
    */

    /*
       01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567  01234567
    0     #      #####       ###     ####      #####     #     #
    1    # #     #    #     #   #    #   #       #       #     #
    2   #   #    #    #    #         #    #      #       #     #
    3   #   #    #####     #         #    #      #       #     #
    4   #####    #    #    #         #    #      #       #  #  #
    5  #     #   #    #     #   #    #   #       #       # # # #
    6  #     #   #####       ###     ####      # #        #   #
    7                                           #
    */

    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Hi, On what logic is the map[][] created ? I can see that the rows represent the individual characters. On what logic have we set the values in this 2d array ?

Comment: @cs-dev the map[][] is a straight port of the various C versions below. It's just a lookup table that defines a font made up of the other characters |'d together,